# Is it possible to pass error information from UploadHandler to view?

Tags: django, django-views

I have a custom upload handler in Django which checks content_type and raises a SkipFile exception is the content type is not correct. I cannot figure out how to pass the error information over to my view which is responsible for handling the POST request.

How can an uploadHandler pass error information back to the view?

Comment: similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1233938/django-file-upload-handler-errors